# How to convert the vector of shared_ptr<Derived> to shared_ptr<Base>?

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I want to convert the vector of `shared_ptr<Derived>`  to the vector of `shared_ptr<Base>`:

```
class Base
{
};
class Derived : public Base
{
};


size_t ConvertVecBasePtr(const vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>& p)
{
    return p.size();
}


int main()
{
    vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived>> d;
    ConvertVecBasePtr(d);
    return 0;
}
```

I got error of `ConvertVecBasePtr`:

> error C2664: 'size_t ConvertVecBasePtr(const std::vectorstd::shared_ptr<Base,std::allocatorstd::shared_ptr<Base>> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vectorstd::shared_ptr<Derived,std::allocatorstd::shared_ptr<Derived>>' to 'const std::vectorstd::shared_ptr<Base,std::allocatorstd::shared_ptr<Base>> &'

Could you help me fix it? For example: can I use another container instead of std::vector?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` can be converted to `std::shared_ptr<Base>`, but vectors of such are not convertible. You need to create a new vector, in which you will push converted pointers.

Answer (score 4):

You might construct the new vector in place like that:

`ConvertVecBasePtr({d.begin(), d.end()});`

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question was about **conversion** but is conversion necessary? If not then something like this may or may not be applicable for your use-case (whatever that is).

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>


struct Base{};

struct Derived : public Base{};


template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, std::size_t>::type
getSize(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>& p)
{
    return p.size();
}

int main(int, char**)
{   
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived>> v{ std::make_shared<Derived>(), std::make_shared<Derived>() };
    auto n = getSize(v);    
    std::cout << "size = " << n << '\n';    
    return 0;
}
```

Just a thought. If it's no use to you please forget I ever spoke.